# C# WPF enable control based on CheckBox value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I know I can bind a control, say `TextBox` to a `CheckBox` value using the following code:

```
<CheckBox Name="cb1" />
<TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=cb1, Path=IsChecked}" />
```

How can I do the same in a `DataGrid` ?

I have a `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid Name="xDataGridName" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Enable">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                   <flatcheckbox:FlatCheckBox x:Name="xDGCheck" Margin="0" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Enabled, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </DataTemplate>                                              
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <flatcheckbox:FlatCheckBox x:Name="xDGCheck" Margin="0" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Enabled, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>



        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Group">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                   <TextBlock Name="xTextBlockName" Text="{Binding Path=Group}" />
                </DataTemplate>                                              
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

                    <!-- this is always enabled, i want it to be enable only when checkbox is checked -->    
                    <TextBlock Name="xTextBlockName" Text="{Binding Path=Group}" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=xDGCheck, Path=IsChecked}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

How can implement the binding in a `DataGrid` ?

Comment: What is `FlatCheckBox`? Can it be replaced with just usual `CheckBox`, or it's important for the question?

Comment: You bind to the `Enabled` source property.

Comment: And why not just `IsEnabled="{Binding Path=Enabled}`, if you are anyway propagating the state into the VM?

Comment: @Vlad `FlatCheckBox` is just a CheckBox with custom styling applied to it. And I'm binding it to the checkbox value ( and not to `Enabled` ) because I want the textbox to be enabled/disabled immediately when I check/uncheck the checkbox. Binding it to Enabled, I have to check the checkbox, lose focus of the row, only then the textbox becomes enabled, and vice versa

Comment: @mrid I think this is the real problem to solve. Did you try specifying the UpdateSourceTrigger? IsChecked="{Binding Path=Enabled, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"

Comment: @Hyarus: Good catch. I included this in my answer.

Comment: @Hyarus Thanks, I didn't know such a thing existed. It's working!!

Comment: What is the meaning of Enabling/Disabling a TextBlock ? Or did you actually mean TextBox ?

Answer (score 2):

You should bind to the `Enabled` source property instead of binding to the `IsChecked` property of the `CheckBox`:

```
<TextBlock Name="xTextBlockName" Text="{Binding Path=Group}" IsEnabled="{Binding Enabled}"/>
```

The `Enabled` property of your data class is set by the `CheckBox` so it should always have the same value as the `IsChecked` property of the `CheckBox`.

Make sure that your data object - the class where the `Enabled` property is defined - implements the [INotifyPropertyChanged interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-implement-the-inotifypropertychanged-interface) and raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the `Enabled` property when it is set by the `CheckBox`.

As pointed out by @Hyarus, you should also set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged` for the source property to get set immediately:

```
<flatcheckbox:FlatCheckBox x:Name="xDGCheck" Margin="0" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Enabled, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Comment: @mrid: I don't understand. Your CheckBox is bound to a source property called Enabled, isn't it? If not, it should be.

Comment: this is what is happening: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/16s5s5II2cdeIelirKn038ODe23hecVMy

Comment: Please update your question instead of providing a link to Google Drive. By the way, did you see my last edit?

Comment: +1 But i think you need to add the UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged to the checkbox (or both). It is a problem of the checkbox not updating the property, not the textblock getting the update.

Answer (score 0):

As you already having `Enabled` property binded with your `CheckBox`, you can use the same to bind it with `IsEnabled` property of your `TextBox`. Your `CheckBox` binding should've `UpdateSourceTrigger` set to `PropertyChanged` Working sample below,

**XAML**

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Enable">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Enabled, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Group">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Group}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Group}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=Enabled, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**Model**

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private bool _enabled;
    private string _group;

    public bool Enabled
    {
        get => _enabled; set
        {
            _enabled = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Enabled)));
        }
    }

    public string Group
    {
        get { return _group; }
        set
        {
            _group = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Group)));
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Model> Items { get; set; }
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Model>
        {
            {new Model{ Enabled = true, Group = "Group1"} },
            {new Model{ Enabled = false, Group = "Group2"} },
            {new Model{ Enabled = false, Group = "Group3"} },
            {new Model{ Enabled = true, Group = "Group4"} },
            {new Model{ Enabled = false, Group = "Group5"} },
            {new Model{ Enabled = false, Group = "Group6"} }
        };
    }
}
```